# Differentiation for vector-valued functions is interesting. Integration for vector-valued functions is uninteresting. Why?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, soft-question

I am reading "Introduction to Analysis 1" by Mitsuo Sugiura (in Japanese).

Mitsuo Sugiura defined differentiation for vector-valued functions in the book.
The following definition from "Analysis on Manifolds" by J. R. Munkres is the same definition in "Introduction to Analysis 1" by Mitsuo Sugiura.

1. Differentiation for vector-valued functions:
   From J. R. Munkres "Analysis on Manifolds":

> **Definition.** Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^m$, let $f:A\to\mathbb{R}^m$. Suppose $A$ contains a neighborhood of $a$. We say that $f$ is **differentiable** at $a$ if there is an $n$ by $m$ matrix $B$ such that $$\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-B\cdot h}{|h|}\to 0\text{ as }h\to0.$$

---

2. Integration for vector-valued functions:
   Mitsuo Sugiura defined integrals for vector-valued functions as the limit of a Riemann sum in "Introduction to Analysis 1".

---

There is an interesting theorem about differentiation for vector-valued functions. For example, the inverse function theorem.

But Mitsuo Sugiura wrote only one uninteresting proposition about integration for vector-valued functions:
$$\int_I f=\left(\int_I f_1,\dots,\int_I f_m\right).$$

Differentiation for vector-valued functions is interesting.
Integration for vector-valued functions is uninteresting.

Is there any reason?

Comment: In both cases, changing the target space from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}^n$ (or any other finite-dimensional real/complex vector space) is uninteresting because you just do things component wise (things get slightly more interesting/difficult/technical in infinite-dimensions). Both become interesting when you change the domain (from an interval $I\subset\Bbb{R}$ to an open set $A\subset\Bbb{R}^m$ for differentiation, and an interval $[a,b]$+RIemann integrals to an arbitrary measure space $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$+Lebesgue integral+ measurable functions)

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you very much for your explanation.